# how to fix terraform lookup function error

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to setup a dns dynamically so depending on the workspace (I'm on my sandbox)

I can update the dns of my service.

So within my module I have created a route53 record like this:

```
resource "aws_route53_record" "app" {
  zone_id = data.aws_route53_zone.zone.zone_id
  name    = "${lookup(var.subdomain, terraform.workspace)}.${data.aws_route53_zone.zone.name}"
  type    = "CNAME"
  ttl     = "300"

  records = [aws_lb.api.dns_name]
}
```

where `subdomain` is a variable defined as :

```
variable "subdomain" {
  description = "Subdomain per environment"
  type        = map(string)
  default = {
    production = "api"
    staging    = "api.staging"
    dev        = "api.dev"
  }
}
```

but when I run plan I get

```
│ Error: Error in function call
│ 
│   on ../module/dns.tf line 7, in resource "aws_route53_record" "app":
│    7:   name    = "${lookup(var.subdomain, terraform.workspace)}.${data.aws_route53_zone.zone.name}"
│     ├────────────────
│     │ terraform.workspace is "default"
│     │ var.subdomain is map of string with 3 elements
│ 
│ Call to function "lookup" failed: lookup failed to find 'default'.
```

Comment: Well, for one, you are in a workspace not defined with the `var.subdomain` variable.

Comment: adding an extra key to the map solved it

Comment: Are you using Terraform Cloud with `backend "remote"`? This behavior of the workspace always showing as "default" seems familiar as a quirk of that backend.